# playing .avi,divx,mov video formats in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am developing an android project in which i need to play .avi,mov,divx format videos.I think android doesn't support these formats.

I have downloaded ffmpeg codec and loaded the library "libffmpeg.so" in my project using android ndk and JNI.

```
Now,how can i use this "libffmpeg.so" to play those video formats.
```

My project directory structure is like this.

[image]

Any one please help.

Comment: There are no such things as "ffmpeg format videos". ffmpeg provides a set of tools to help with various things related to AV media including recording, transcoding, remuxing, playback - ffmpeg is NOT an audio or video format. What is/are the actual format(s) of videos you are actually trying to play?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need to play these formats .avi,.mkv,mov,mp4,quicktime etc..

Comment: As I commented on your question about using RockPlayer...if you have a media player app on your device then simply create an `Intent` with `ACTION_VIEW` and use the intent's `setData(Uri data)` method to set the path of the media file. You can also use the intent's `setType(String type)` method to set the MIME type if needed. You then simply call `startActivity(Intent intent)` and Android will attempt to find an app which can view it. Assuming RockPlayer can view it then it should work.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try playing your file in [Daroon Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.daroonsoft.player&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5kYXJvb25zb2Z0LnBsYXllciJd). I was also not able to play MP4 video file for rtsp streaming. Using Daroon helped me solve my issue. It plays avi files too

Comment: Thanks a lot Rashmi,i think Daroon player will do. Is there any way i can get the working source code of Daroon player.

Comment: I dont know about the source code But you can get its apk files, its available on net :)

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. If you get the source code of Daroon, kindly send me the link as well....thank you

Comment: Daroon Player, link removed